# Is the physical mass of the electron a gauge invariant quantity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, gauge-invariance

In Lattice, one cannot calculate gauge non-invariant quantities, such as the quark mass. This is because one averages over the gauge and gets 0.

One way to get around the issue is to fix the gauge. But the resulting quark mass will be gauge dependent. It is hard to interpret the meaning of this quantity, as free quarks cannot be found in nature. While quarks are confined, electrons are not. It is of course possible that while the Lattice calculation is gauge dependent, the final result is not.

However, a Lattice theorist recently told me that "it is known that the physical mass of the electron is a gauge dependent quantity. And what we measure in the lab (using spectrometer for example) is not the electron's mass". This is somewhat surprising to me. I did some search and couldn't find any references on it. Can someone comments on this issue?

**Related questions**:

- [Gauge-invariance of pole mass using Ward Identity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45095/gauge-invariance-of-pole-mass-using-ward-identity)

**References**:

- Ward, B. F. L. "On gauge invariance of the renormalized Z $^{0} $ rest mass." Phys. Lett. B 296.IC-91-161 (1991): 209-212.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45095/gauge-invariance-of-pole-mass-using-ward-identity). "What we measure in the lab is not *the* electron's mass" is pointlessly oracular. It is *a* mass that CODATA fixes just fine.

Comment: I would ask for an explicit demonstration that a gauge transformation can alter either the observed mass or the bare mass. It's my understanding that such transformations can only fiddle with the metric of the functional integral, but I don't know how gauge transformations interact with renormalization.

Comment: You were told wrong--if you are relating the verbatim statements. Electrons are asymptotic states and physical observables such as masses are gauge invariant, unlike Green's functions/propagators and much of the renormalization procedure. In QED, even running electron masses are gauge invariant. I don't understand why you are using lattice gauge theory (normally utilized for QCD, where the fields are *not* physical asymptotic states) to discuss electron masses and QED....

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the reply - I see your point. I used lattice QCD because our conversation started with it and I guess my mind was stuck with it for a while. I was wondering if Lattice QCD can explain confinement. I always get confusing answers from these conversations, this one [GI of electron mass] included.

Comment: Lattice QCD motivates and confirms confinement--I'm not sure it completely proves or "explains" it... But that's a different question, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm sure it does - but I am learning more about it. Euclidean QFT has non-physical components (i.e. has no Minkowskian correspondence). I'd love to know if and which the things we calculated in lattice QCD are physical. Of course, this is only one way to look at confinement. As you suggested, even proposing an operator that explains confinement is a challenging question. (A related question is lattice is a blackbox, how do we know the numbers we crunched out make sense? Interesting to think.)